# Dynamic Breadcrumbs on Product View with Full Page Cache Enabled

Tags: magento-enterprise, template, full-page-cache, breadcrumbs

### Situation

We have a breadcrumb block on our product details page. With multiple category trees directing users to a single product page, the breadcrumb trail should change depending on the category which made the referral.

In our case, if Full Page Cache (`FPC`) is disabled -- the Breadcrumbs are dynamic and it works like I described.

With `FPC` enabled, the breadcrumb gets fixed on the initial non-cached page request.

### Question

How would I go about getting the breadcrumb block to be dynamic on the product page? It's perfectly fine if it's being cached on category results pages.

Comment: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/understanding-full-page-cache/

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in etc/cache.xml file in your any module or make small module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <catalog_breadcrumbs>
            <block>page/html_breadcrumbs</block>
            <name>breadcrumbs</name>
            <placeholder>CONTAINER_BREADCRUMBS</placeholder>
            <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Breadcrumbs</container>
            <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
        </catalog_breadcrumbs>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have shared a solution for the breadcrumbs issue in the below discussion.
Please go through it, I was facing the same issue before enabling this configuration.

I found the best and quickest solution by adding a category path to the links using the below configuration.

*Store Configurations > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs*

[image]

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/371758/95447