# FPC issue with same product in multiple categories

Tags: magento2.4, category-products, full-page-cache

I have an issue I am trying to solve regarding caching. I have products that are in multiple categories and whichever one is visited first is the one that's cached. When navigating to the same product but in a different category it is pulling the cached version and not from the current category it is in. This is leading to design errors and issues of that nature as we have some styling per category and if it's pulling the cached category and not the category it's currently in then the design gets all weird.

Would anyone either know how to check if the page is in the correct category you are navigating to so i can bypass the cache if(cached_page_category_id != requested_page_category_id) or if you can save the page cache based off the category id and pull based on the category id?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue too,

I was having an issue with breadcrumbs if one product is assigned in multiple categories. When we click on the product PDP link the first time, it caches the product page and then when I check that product from another category, it shows the old category breadcrumb.

I found the best and quickest solution by **adding a category path to the links** using the below configuration.

**Store Configurations** > **Catalog** > **Catalog** > **Search Engine Optimization** > **Use Categories Path for Product URLs**

[image: Configuration Screenshot]

You can also use this setting in your case and let me know if it works for you.

Mark as an accepted solution if this solution works. Thanks in advance.